# Change from using fontawesome icon to an image

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

```
<script>
var today = new Date();
var hourNow = today.getHours();
var greeting;
var icon;

if (hourNow < 12) {
    greeting = "Good Morning";
    icon = "coffee";
} else if (hourNow < 20) {
    greeting = "Good afternoon!";
    icon = "sun";
} else if (hourNow < 24) {
    greeting = "Good evening";
    icon = "moon";
} else {
    greeting = "Welcome";
}

document.getElementById("col-1").innerHTML = "<h3>" + greeting + " </h1>";

document.getElementById("icon").innerHTML =
'<i class="fas fa-' + icon + '" aria-hidden="true"></i>';

</script>
```

This is the code I am using above - the icon name is added after the "fas fa-"
How can I not use font awesome and just have an image appear for the different times of the day instead?
Thanks

Comment: better write classes and toggle em on condition.
something like

var element = document.getElementById("refer_meaning");
element.classList.toggle("mystyle");

This will help you remove class and add new class with image as background etc.

Comment: If you wanna use image only here is the way to update img src.

    `document.getElementById("imageid").src="<img path>";`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the URLs with images of your choice:

```
if (hourNow < 12) {
    greeting = "Good Morning";
    icon = "https://picsum.photos/50";
} else if (hourNow < 20) {
    greeting = "Good afternoon!";
    icon = "https://picsum.photos/50";
} else if (hourNow < 24) {
    greeting = "Good evening";
    icon = "https://picsum.photos/50";
} else {
    greeting = "Welcome";
}

document.getElementById("col-1").innerHTML = "<h3>" + greeting + " </h3>";

document.getElementById("icon").innerHTML = `<img src=${icon} alt="">`;
```

Also, fix the closing tag of your heading.